# Script to remove exif, in uploaded photos?

Tags: javascript, database, phpmyadmin, exif

I’m trying to figure out how I can filter exif data, before file or photo upload to DB. Is this possible with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

No reason why it would not be possible, but it's not something that is easy for a beginner.

A quick google gave me.
https://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader

I assume it should work, but again, if you are new to javascript and coding in general you might not succeed using it.
But try, if nothing else you will learn things while trying.

Comment: Found this: https://auth0.com/blog/read-edit-exif-metadata-in-photos-with-javascript/

Comment: Near the bottom it talks about piexifjs, a linkable script with integrated commands.